# dimensionality reduction with PCA in raster brick

Tags: r, pca, r-raster, svd

Based on the examples here:

[How to perform dimensionality reduction with PCA in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57467/how-to-perform-dimensionality-reduction-with-pca-in-r/57478#57478)

and

[How to reverse PCA and reconstruct original variables from several principal components?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com)

I am trying to perform a PCA on a raster brick (with 69 layers), then get the leading PCs and finally reconstruct the original variables using only the PC with a cumulative proportion of around ~95%.

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

ln <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/d88iuvp9oio14zk/test.nc?dl=1" # ~400 kb size

### DOWNLOAD THE FILE
download.file(ln,
              destfile="test.nc",
              method="auto")

st <- brick("test.nc")
nlayers(st)

### DO THE PCA
pca <- prcomp(st[]) 
# to visualize pcs as rasters
x <- predict(st, pca, index=1:4)
spplot(x) # there are the first 4 PCs explaining most of the data.
```

Then I am trying to reconstruct the original variables from the first 4 PCs since I am interested in the spatial distribution of these:

```
### PCA DETAILS
summary(pca) # importance of components
plot (pca) # scree plot
loadings(pca) #eigens 

mu <- colMeans(as.matrix(st)) # get the column means to use after

#### REDUCTION
nComp <- 4
Xhat <- pca$x[,1:nComp] %*% t(pca$rotation[,1:nComp])
Xhat <- scale(Xhat, center = -mu, scale = FALSE)
```

Here I thought I will get only the first 4 PCs. However, I am ending up with 69 as before:

```
### CHECK THE DIMENSIONS
dim(Xhat)

### THEN CREATE THE RASTER WITH THE PCs
coords <- coordinates(st[[1]]) # get the lon/lat

rst <- cbind(coords, Xhat) # bind the coordinates 
rst <- rasterFromXYZ(rst) # create the raster
plot(rst)
```

What did I missed here? I am no expert in PCA but the original idea was to have a smaller number of layers able to explain the patterns in the original data.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When asking a question here, please do not point to a file on dropbox, but include some example data like this:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
s <- stack(b, flip(b, "y"), setValues(raster(b), runif(ncell(b))))
names(s) <- paste0("var", 1:nlayers(s))    

pca <- prcomp(values(s)) 
x <- predict(s, pca, index=1:4)
```

You create `Xhat` by subsetting the PCs, but pca$rotation has all the variables

```
round(pca$rotation[,1:nComp],1)
      PC1  PC2  PC3  PC4
var1 -0.4  0.4 -0.4  0.4
var2 -0.4  0.4 -0.2  0.2
var3 -0.4  0.4  0.6 -0.6
var4 -0.4 -0.4 -0.4 -0.4
var5 -0.4 -0.4 -0.2 -0.2
var6 -0.4 -0.4  0.6  0.6
var7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

And that makes sense since you are saying that you want "to reconstruct the original variables from the first 4 PCs since I am interested in the spatial distribution of these". All variables contribute to the PCs.

What you may really want is `plot(x)` ?

You are using poor code to create a RasterBrick from `Xhat`. You can do this instead:

```
Xhat <- pca$x[,1:nComp] %*% t(pca$rotation[,1:nComp])
Xhat <- scale(Xhat, scale = FALSE)

b <- brick(s, values=FALSE)
b <- setValues(b, Xhat)
b
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777, 7  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : memory
#names      :          var1,          var2,          var3,          var4,          var5,          var6,          var7 
#min values : -184.32344039, -184.48714657, -193.05823803, -184.32341010, -184.48718831, -193.05827512,   -0.01466663 
#max values :   73.33872354,   70.38724578,   63.48912986,   73.33875039,   70.38723822,   63.48906605,    0.01193009
```

Compare b and s

```
m <- cellStats(s, mean)
bb <- b + m
plot(bb, s)
```